# Convert log level (log4net)

Tags: log4net

I want to convert an INFO log level to a WARN if the INFO log message contains an exception. Is there anyway I can accomplish this? (I am integrating log4net in a .NET application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you already wrap your logging calls, in which case you could intercept the messages before passing them to log4net, your best bet would be to create your own appenders which promote log events as appropriate. As each appender subclass would need the exact same code I've created an extension method which does the actual promotion:

```
public static class AppenderExtensions
{
    public static LoggingEvent Promote(this LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (loggingEvent.Level != Level.Info 
         || loggingEvent.ExceptionObject == null)
        {
            return loggingEvent;
        }

        var data = loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData(FixFlags.All);
        data.Level = Level.Warn;
        return new LoggingEvent(data);
    }
}

public class PromotingAdoNetAppender : AdoNetAppender
{
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        base.Append(loggingEvent.Promote());
    }
}

public class PromotingRollingFileAppender : RollingFileAppender
{
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        base.Append(loggingEvent.Promote());
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is to declare these appender types in your config:

```
<appender name="DatabaseAppender" 
          type="Your.Namespace.Here.PromotingAdoNetAppender">
          …
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, I went along with your first suggestion and created a wrapper around the log4net logger. This way I don't need to use custom loggers and still get the desired results.